# DotNetOpenAuth I need some help please

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I know this has been posted before, but never really answered, I'm using the DotNetOpenAuth to try and do GoogleID login, and every time I do `details = OResponse.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();` I always, always, always get back null, I don't get whats the point of the GoogleID if I can't get back any information, I would think at the very least I would get an email address, so I could associate it other login information in my databse. I just don't understand could really use some help, Im probably just looking at openID in the wrong way.

I'm using ASP.NET and looking to use openID/Facebook as my sole means of logging in users, I really don't want to mess with membership roles, or extra junk that ASP.NET likes to add.

Comment: I've tried the simple control inculded with the openautho dll, i've tried this http://www.midnightprogrammer.net/post/Extending-OpenID-Implementation-With-ASPNET-User-Information-Roles-and-Membership.aspx, and even that project gets back null, are you just supposed to use the URL returned by the response, would that be your unique identifier.

Comment: Don't have time to help right now, but check out http://test-id.org/ -- you can make requests from there to see if it really is Google or if it's something on your end

Comment: yes, you should *always* use the `IAuthenticationResponse.ClaimedIdentifier` as the unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this has been asked and answered many times.  Google *does* support AX.  But it ignores any attributes marked as "optional".  So if you want the email address, you have to say that email address is a required attribute.

The `ClaimsResponse` extension you're checking for isn't AX -- it's Simple Registration.  But if you have [AXFetchAsSregTransform](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/the-axfetchassregtransform-behavior/) behavior turned on (highly recommended) then it allows you to just use `ClaimsRequest` and `ClaimsResponse` exclusively, and DotNetOpenAuth will automatically translate to and from AX behind-the-scenes for you.

Alternatively, you can use `FetchReqest` and `FetchResponse` to speak AX directly to Google.

**But** (and I can't hammer this hard enough), *do not use the email address as the user's unique identifier!!!*  Instead, use the `IAuthenticationResponse.ClaimedIdentifier` string as the unique identifier.  Email address should generally be considered just a helpful hint that can be used to prefill a registration form.  You shouldn't even trust that the email address you get is really under the user's control (that's one reason why it shouldn't be considered their unique id) since the Provider can lie to you.  Google and Yahoo are two providers that promise (if you choose to trust them) that the email addresses have been verified, so you can skip the email validation step for users from them if you wish.

Comment: so I assuming the claim identifier will be unique across multiple sites? And yea, I do have the AXFetcheSregTransform turned on, I've seen that across multiple sites/posts. I tried the FetchRequest/Response, to no avail, I've tried a couple things such as mix and matching, request/required levels. However I did find a link that lets your register your domian with google, perhaps that part of the solution.

Comment: ClaimedIdentifier is unique per user.  It *may also* be (and this is true for Google) unique per "realm" (or site).

Comment: If you'd like to include the logs of your auth request (and response) of your attempt with Google, we can look over it to find out what's going wrong.  You don't need to register your site to get email addresses from Google in my experience.

Comment: what logs are you referring  too? Are you suggesting capturing the html packets as they go in and out....

Comment: The logs DotNetOpenAuth emit when activated.  See http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/

Comment: I got this to finally work, there was and extra character in my webconfig, that does the request transformation. That aside, I did have another question, whats to stop someone from intercepting the returning Claim_URL and modify it to a friends Claim_URL, and making the website look up the wrong user ID. Is the data coming back OpenID provider SSL?, so that can't be hacked?

Comment: Good question.  SSL does *not* protect against data tampering at the browser.  But OpenID does come with a signature from the Provider so that if the user tampers with it (or anyone else when SSL is not in use) the relying party will reject it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that Google's OpenID server supports AX or sreg.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can help me understand OpenID a little better, I don't understand what you get back in the response as an unique indentifier, it seems to me if you don't get back some unique identifier there doesn't seem to be much of a point.

Comment: I haven't gotten that far in my own exploration of OpenID yet, sorry.

Comment: Isn't stackoverflow able to get your your google email address?

Comment: Tell me about it. I can't even find any real-world, readable documentation on how stateful OpenID works.

Comment: I read somewhere that Google supports AX (only), but I can't remember the source, sorry. And yes, StackOverflow gets the email from Google -- I've heard stories of this working elsewhere too :-)

Comment: Well, it certainly doesn't advertise it in its XRDS file.

Comment: I've not heard of "stateful OpenID" before, Jeff.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Andrew OpenID in association mode, with or without the Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Comment: Oh, right.  I typically hear it called "smart" mode, but yes, I don't know why I didn't make the connection.